# How do I use FIND_IN_SET() with a '?' parameter in SSRS Report Builder 3.0?

Tags: mysql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-tablix

My SSRS Server is using an ODBC connection to pull data from a MySQL server. I have a query that's making use of the FIND_IN_SET method. My requirements state that the report should provide options for a start and end date parameter and a comma delimited list of "usernames". The start and end date parameters work fine so I've left them out of my sample code for brevity.

When I run the query in MySQL Workbench, I get results. When I run the query in the query designer of Report Builder 3.0, I get results, **IF AND ONLY IF**, I hard code the value of the parameter being used for the FIND_IN_SET() method. When I try to use a '?' parameter for the value, and paste in the exact same value as when hard coded, I get no results.

This query works in Workbench and the Report Builder's Query Designer:

```
select pwk.username,
    sum(case when pwk.event = '/some-value/' then pwk.count else 0 end) 
    as order_detail_count
from table pwk
where find_in_set(pwk.username, 'foosername@test.net,foo2@test.com,username@test.org')
```

This same query returns nothing when I use the '?' parameter and copy/paste the above value when running the query:

```
select pwk.username,
    sum(case when pwk.event = '/some-value/' then pwk.count else 0 end) 
    as order_detail_count
from table pwk
where find_in_set(pwk.username, ?)
```

It seems as though the Report Builder is not using the text parameter the way I expect it to but I have no way to determine how to use it "correctly". Has anyone ever run into this problem?

I would expect the results to be identical but that's not the case. Is there a way to use FIND_IN_SET with a text parameter? Or is there some other way to accomplish this? I'm perfectly okay with using something other than FIND_IN_SET if it will work. I tried using IN() but that didn't even work in WorkBench. My users just need to be able to enter multiple usernames as a parameter.

If it's relevant, I'm using a Tablix to display the data.

Comment: Make sure you don't have any spaces around the commas when you paste the parameter.

Comment: @Barmar - Confirmed. No spaces and still does not work. I have also confirmed that setting a default value for the parameter does not work either. :(

Comment: Oh, it's probably worth mentioning that using a single "username" instead of a comma delimited string does not work either. I'd expect that to return the exact same results are it would in WorkBench so that one blew my mind.

Comment: Does it work if you change to `pwk.username = ?` and put a single username in the parameter?

Comment: I figured out the problem. Unfortunately, it had nothing to do with anything I'd explained in the question. It was a simple misunderstanding that there is a difference between the parameters of the query and the parameters of the report. When I aligned the two correctly, everything started working. Thanks for your help, @Barmar :)